# Image processing in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I was working on a project name symptom based disease diagnosis in android.
As android is java based, so I am implementing the the color matching algorithm directly in java first using image processing libraries like OpenCV etc. I was wondering if I completed the matching process and after that when I embed it into my android code, what if it didn't embed? That's why I am posting this question if I am going right with FIRST developing method in java then embed it into android or should I continue it directly with android??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its true the Java is used the programming language in android development, but android apps has an architecture and a pattern that must be respected during development. Note also that Java libraries are not android Libraries. Before using a library, you need to be sure that library has being development for the android platform you are targeting.
Before using a library, you need to import it into your project. Check how to do it for the IDE you are using. Also, you don't develop out of the android development environment and embed the codes later as you just did. That is bad programming practices.

Comment: I don't fully agree. Developing vision algorithms in different enviroments from the target plattform is a common thing to do and even advisable, especially when targeting limited plattforms. During prototyping vision algorithms you will benefit from a well debuggble and fast system. After solving your algorithmic problem you can find ways to integrate your stuff, as long as you understand the underlying mechanisms of the algorithm and limitations of your target plattform.